# Passing Multiple Sheetnames into Array Google App Script not working on a timestamp function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is there something I'm missing here on this script? when the variable for sheet_name is set to a single sheet it works perfectly, when I change sheet_names to an array ["sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3", "sheet4"] it doesn't fire (on edit)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var COLUMN_TO_CHECK = [1,4,5]; // The columns to check if something is entered. (Columns A & B)
  var DATE_TIME_COLUMN = 13; // Where you want the date time stamp (Column C)
  var SHEET_NAME = ["User1", "User2", "User3"]; // Sheet you are working on

  var editedCell = e.range;
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (editedSheet.getName() === SHEET_NAME) {
    if (COLUMN_TO_CHECK.indexOf(editedCell.getColumn()) != -1) {
      var allFilled = true;
      var editedRow = editedCell.getRow();
      for (var i in COLUMN_TO_CHECK) {
        if (editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, COLUMN_TO_CHECK[i]).getValue() == "") {
          allFilled = false;
        }
      }
      if (allFilled) {
        editedSheet.getRange(editedRow,DATE_TIME_COLUMN).setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show it to us with the array instead?

Comment: Done for you buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`editedSheet.getName()` is a String. `SHEET_NAME` is an Array. These will never be equal (`===`).

Use `SHEET_NAME.indexOf(editedSheet) != -1`, since [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) will return `-1` if not present.

Updated code (pluralizing `SHEET_NAME` to `SHEET_NAMES`):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var COLUMN_TO_CHECK = [1,4,5]; // The columns to check if something is entered. (Columns A & B)
  var DATE_TIME_COLUMN = 13; // Where you want the date time stamp (Column C)
  var SHEET_NAMES = ["User1", "User2", "User3"]; // Sheet you are working on

  var editedCell = e.range;
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (SHEET_NAMES.indexOf(editedSheet.getName()) != -1) {
    if (COLUMN_TO_CHECK.indexOf(editedCell.getColumn()) != -1) {
      var allFilled = true;
      var editedRow = editedCell.getRow();
      for (var i in COLUMN_TO_CHECK) {
        if (editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, COLUMN_TO_CHECK[i]).getValue() == "") {
          allFilled = false;
        }
      }
      if (allFilled) {
        editedSheet.getRange(editedRow,DATE_TIME_COLUMN).setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Am I to wrap this within the if statement? for eg : IF (SHEET_NAME.indexOf(editedSheet) != -1)

Comment: @Datanovice Exactly. I've update my answer with your entire script to show you exactly where it goes.

Comment: You are a true G, thanks for your help & explanation!

Comment: @Datanovice Glad to help. Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it worked for you.